# Magento(1.9) pagination issue

Tags: magento-1.9, pagination

I have wrote the pagination functionality,in the below code i set the pagination 4 for each page,but unfortunately i got all the records in first page itself,and even the second page also the entire records display, the only good thing is page size is working fine(i means page count). see the below code for better understanding.

### block file code

```
class Federallawyer_Flpackage_Block_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $collection =  Mage::getModel('flpackage/packages')->PackageCollection();
        //$collection->getSelect()->limit(4);
        //echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString(); exit;
        $this->setCollection($collection);
    }

    public function getPagerHtml() {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
        $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(4=>4)); //Now you can get 4 items in a page.
        $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**see the attached screens**
[image]

Comment: can you post the contents of `PackageCollection` method?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you swap the limit and get collection lines on the pager?
i.e.

```
$pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
$pager->setAvailableLimit(array(4=>4)); //Now you can get 4 items in a page.
```

tho I'm not sure what this array(4=>4) does

Comment: array(4=>4) is nothing but use for per page count, then i tried the above code, still no positive response.

Comment: maybe try with `setPageSize(4)`?

Comment: even i tried with the above code but still no response.